# How to handle dynamically generated values during run time via Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

**Scenario**: I am recording a script which is fetching values from CSV name and email. I have used `${email}` and `${name}` at the time which candidate is registering. Every time candidate register, unique instance Id is generated on the basis of which further action is performed.

Ex:

> Candidate registers -> Unique Id (say 12345) -> ST : Start some test
>   on the website -> Some responses saved for 12345 -> FT : Finish test
>   on website

Need to perform the same for say 500 candidates. I am fetching unique email and name from csv.
How do i store/handle unique instance Id for each candidate dynamically and perform the entire operation?
Currently each operation is getting performed for same unique instance Id (12345) with 0% error.

Let me know if any other details needed for the same.

---

**UPDATE from comments:**

I can use say `UniqueId` whenever candidate registers using a RegEx Extractor or a XPath Extractor and i can pass that value in further process.
Now issue is i have to pass the stored variable in JSON.
No clue about that.

Comment: Got half of the solution. I can use say UniqueId whenever candidate register using  a regex extractor or a xpath extractor and i can pass that value in further process. Now issue is i have to pass the stored variable in JSON. No clue about that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've extracted UniqueId value using any extractor component it's stored in jmeter variable (pointed in the extractor's configuration) and can be referred as e.g. `${uniqueId}`.

To pass into the further request you can use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) where in `Post Body` you can set your JSON request code with `${uniqueId}` inserted in the right place.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression extractor in jmeter to extract required variable value and store reference it with a variable name .

Later it can be used in later requests  by usin ${variablename}

In the regular expression extractor you can use perl5 regular expressions

Refer to this link for additional information:
http://www.jmeter4u.com/2013/04/chapter-6-handling-dynamic-server-values.html